# How do I add username/password access to phpMyAdmin, independent of 'linked' servers?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

We have about 10 databases (and counting) on different servers that we have to manage and jump between quite quickly, and it's becoming highly unproductive to continuously enter each server's password every time we access it.

I want to implement global username/password access to phpMyAdmin. I have tried using our intranet's existing user authentication process, which uses PHP sessions, but this interferes with phpMyAdmin's use of sessions.

Is there a way that I can do this? A plugin? Is there a protocol in the PMA code I need to be aware of?

Basically, I have tried inserting this in `config.inc.php`, but it is just ignored:

```
if ( isset ( $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] ) and $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] == true)
{
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'remote.database.server.net';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'database1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password123';
    // etc - for all servers/databases
}
```

I have also tried inserting this at the top of phpMyAdmin's `index.php` but it also gets ignored:

```
if ( ! isset ( $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] ) or $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] != TRUE )
{
    exit ( header( "Location: https://myintranet.com/login" ) );
}
```

I even included `if( session_id() == "" ) session_start();` in both situations, but then it tells me:

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "PMA_Theme_Manager" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /usr/www/users/me/myintranet.com/pma/libraries/common.inc.php on line 686

Am I fighting a losing battle?

Comment: https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types Guess you'll need something like single sign-on

Comment: Personally I would not use phpMyAdmin at all. There are several good db admin products around like Navicat/TOAD/HEIDI and of course the MySQL Workbench itself http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ . Use one of those to manage your servers and databases. All of them allow you to store the logins for each connection and to have connections open to multiple servers.

Comment: @DavidSoussan: Unfortunately, costs is a factor for us at the moment. I have been using an excellent product called FlySpeed SQL Query, by Active Database Software, but the trial/free version has many limitations. So it has to be a free option for now.

Comment: The mysql workbench is free, as are TOAD and HEIDI. Check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how robust or secure this solution it is but is has worked so far. Any warnings are welcome.

I used the following in `config.inc.php`:

```
if( session_id() == "" ) session_start();

if ( isset ( $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] ) and $_SESSION["myIntranetAuth"] == true)
{
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'remote.database.server.net';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'database1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password123';
    // etc - for all servers/databases
}
```

And commented out `session_start()` in `session.inc.php` (line 101, version 4.3.8, otherwise unmodified) to remove persistent 'session already started' messages.

Answer (score 0):

As Blaatpraat mentioned in a comment, the ideal way to do this properly in phpMyAdmin is using the 'signon' auth_type.

An alternative which is slightly more cumbersome but much less work is to set each server to auth_type config and secure your phpMyAdmin installation by some other means (such as a `.htaccess` file enforcing HTTP BASIC authentication -- or the existing authentication process you mention). That way, your users are not prompted to log in to each server individually, and your webserver provides authentication to secure the phpMyAdmin installation. The downside here is that each user then uses the same MySQL user account, which is either a benefit or detriment depending on your configuration.